# iOS 9 push segue is causing my app to crash

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue, ios9, xcode7-beta5

In iOS 8.4, simulator and phone, I experience no issue with my performSegue call, but when using the simulator on Xcode 7 beta 5, when the performSegue call is made, it crashes. The call stack is below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001137509b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001131c8deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001136179d5 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901
3   Foundation                          0x0000000110c42aa1 -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 106
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011366beb2 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 162
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011366bc1f -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 335
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011366baa3 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 723
7   UIKit                               0x00000001119ef467 -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect] + 860
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113691590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
9   UIKit                               0x000000011173ccaa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
10  UIKit                               0x0000000111531df4 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
11  UIKit                               0x0000000111532720 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
12  UIKit                               0x0000000111532a22 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
13  UIKit                               0x0000000111538e33 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
14  UIKit                               0x0000000111565cba -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1177
15  UIKit                               0x00000001115752f7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
16  UIKit                               0x00000001115761ad -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
17  UIKit                               0x00000001117082d1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
18  UIKit                               0x0000000111459a3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001110f336a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
20  QuartzCore                          0x00000001110e7bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
21  QuartzCore                          0x00000001110e7a4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
22  QuartzCore                          0x00000001110dc1d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001111099f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
24  UIKit                               0x00000001113d5eb0 _afterCACommitHandler + 174
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011367c457 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011367c3c7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011367201b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113671918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
29  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115ee3ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
30  UIKit                               0x00000001113ac99e UIApplicationMain + 171
31  MyApp                               0x000000010fbfe59f main + 111
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011429c92d start + 1
33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It doesn't look like it has anything to do with my code since it's happening during the transition and none of my own functions are in the call stack.

Has anybody experienced this, and/or know how to solve this? I put breakpoints in every function of my second view controller and none of them were hit.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I am having the same problem with xCode 7 - iOS 9 final release.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure this is bug.  In my situation it was segue pointed to TabBarView.

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("tabSegue",sender: nil)
```

When it starts crashing(this happening times to times without changing sb) i just remove segue from storyboard and create it back. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some people report that pointing a segue to ViewController instead of NavigationController fix the issue. You may try that option if it fits.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/11153#11153

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to an invalid setup with Referencing Outlet Collections in a .xib file. for my particular project it was related to adding the same UIGestureRecognizer to the gestureRecognizer collection of multiple views. This worked prior to ios 9 but now crashes the program with an identical stack trace. If you know the view controller that causes the crash (and it sounds like you do because you're able to reproduce the crash), you should be able to see an error in the console telling you what is going on. If not I would examine each Referencing Outlet Collection in the .xib file and try to find the one that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the program instead of system. Please take a look at connection inspector to see if there is any unexpected outlet connection or broken outlet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me: I was using custom segue for push. When i replaced custom segue with show segue issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just an issue with Xcode. I still had the problem after installing the final release. I uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled from the App Store and didn't have the problem anymore. Thanks for all the suggested answers though! I've definitely had the issue of a bad segue in Storyboard before, but this time, it was just Xcode.